Transforming an equation from Polar to Ellipsoidal coordinates
How to convert the following polar coordinate equation to ellipsoidal coordinates in (r,\mu), using CoordinateTransform?
Q[rA_, \[Theta]A_] := 
  Q0*(rA*Cos[\[Theta]A]);

Is there any other function that I can use to transform this equation?
Thanks in advance!

Type "CoordinateT" and go the list  down the list to TransformData and click. Execute  CoordinateTransformData[] and look for Polar -> Elliptic, Ellipsoidal are 3d.
